# Align ggplot legend automatically to width of a plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot in R to generate a heatmap. I would like to align the width of the legend in "bottom" position to the width of the ggplot itself.

Example code:

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)

# Create dataframe
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(1,100), y = seq(1,100))

# Add variable
set.seed(123)
df$z <- rnorm(nrow(df))

# Generate plot
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

With the option `legend.key.width = unit(2, "cm")` I was able to set the width manually. However, I am wondering if there is a way to automatically align the width of the legend to the width of the plot?